# (WYSIWYG) tools for typesetting pseudocode in LaTeX?

Tags: pseudocode, wysiwyg

Is there a simple tool (preferably WYSIWYG) that can be used to create *pseudocode* for LaTex documents?

Comment: In my View: with LaTeX, be prepared to get used with coding and remembering some latex command syntax, WYSIWYG tools are very few and will spoil the feel and experience of LaTeX. But [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org/), [Bakoma](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/) and [texmacs](http://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/home/welcome.en.html) are few WYSIWYG latex editors available. Please [search](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3995/how-to-ensure-the-better-organisation-and-availability-of-knowledge-on-tex-sx#comment13480_3995) this site and [ctan search](http://ctan.org/topic/pseudocode) to post a good Q.

Comment: I've no idea what you are really after here: can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Joseph Wright. I went with `Bakoma Tex`

Comment: @texenthusiast Can you make your comment into an answer? Would get the question off the unanswered list. Right now, i don't have a  possible duplicate in mind.

Comment: I've still no idea what the question really wants!

Answer (score 4):

Converting comments into Answer to remove from Unanswered list

In my View: with LaTeX, be prepared to get used with coding and remembering some latex command syntax, WYSIWYG tools are very few and will spoil the feel and experience of LaTeX. But [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org/), [Bakoma](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/) and [texmacs](http://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/home/welcome.en.html) are few WYSIWYG latex editors available. Please [search](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3995/how-to-ensure-the-better-organisation-and-availability-of-knowledge-on-tex-sx#comment13480_3995) this site and [ctan search](http://ctan.org/topic/pseudocode) to post a good Q